Whats wrong with `s/"((?:[^"]|\\")*)"//` parsing a C string in Perl?
It seems I'm sitting on my eyes, because I cannot find out whats wrong with my regular expression:
I'm trying to parse a C source file that contains strings within a line (actually those strings are regular expressions, but that shall be unimportant).
Basically /"([^"]*)"/ should capture the string (without quotes) unless there are double quotes in it.
I could match double-quotes in side the string using /(\\"*)/! too, but I failed to combine both regular expressions:
Using /"((?:[^"]|\\")*)"/ (capture the text between double-quotes until the first non-escaped double-quotes) the capture ends after the first ", as shown in this example debugger session:
  DB<15> $x='"SAMSUNG SSD SM841N? (2\\.5\"? 7mm |mSATA )?(128|256|512)GB( SED)?|"'

  DB<16> x $x =~ s/"((?:[^"]|\\")*)"//
0  1
  DB<17> x $x
0  '? 7mm |mSATA )?(128|256|512)GB( SED)?|"'
  DB<18>

While writing this question, I tried to swap both alternatives, and suddenly it worked:
  DB<18> $x='"SAMSUNG SSD SM841N? (2\\.5\"? 7mm |mSATA )?(128|256|512)GB( SED)?|"'

  DB<19> x $x =~ s/"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"//
0  1
  DB<20> x $x
0  ''
  DB<21>

So aren't regular expressions A|B and B|A equivalent?

I was not familiar with the expression "sitting on my eyes". Assuming that position would be a challenge, even for a contortionist.

The usual phrase is "I'm having tomatoes on my eyes", but even then One might wonder whether they are sticky enough ;-)


Whats wrong with s/"((?:[^"]|\\")*)"//

The problem is that [^"] can match the start of an escape.
As you surmised, you can fix this by changing the order of the alternates since Perl's regex engine tries the alternates in order.
"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"

But that's not robust. As your instincts tell you, it's more robust to write pattern so that the order doesn't matter.
The lack of robustness in your solution means "((?:\\"|[^"])*)" will treat the input "abc\" as a valid string literal when it's not. In other words, your solution assumes the input is valid, whereas a more robust solution does not.
The following is a robust solution:
"((?:[^"\\\n]|\\.)*)"

Optimized:
"((?:[^"\\\n]++|\\.)*+)"

Since it's just as easy to write a robust solution in this case, that would be better.

I also experimented using a non-greedy capture, so that the first non-escaped " would terminate the capture (avoiding [^"]). I played with a look-behind assertion (so that a " may not be preceeded by a \ , but could not get it working in the few attempts I had tried...

Relying on greediness/non-greediness is also non-robust.

Re "I also experimented using a non-greedy capture", It wasn't matching as much as you wanted, so you tried to make it match less???

Re "I played with a look-behind assertion (so that a " may not be preceeded by a \ ,", But " can be preceded by \ . Consider "\\"

As I found the answer while writing the question, I could have canceled asking it, but as I think this might be interesting to others, too, I'll provide my answer here:
From man perlre(1):

Alternatives are tried from left to right, so the first alternative found for which the entire expression matches, is the one that is chosen. This means that alternatives are not necessarily greedy. For example: when matching "foo|foot" against "barefoot", only the "foo" part will match, as that is the first alternative tried, and it successfully matches the target string. (This might not seem important, but it is important when you are capturing matched text using parentheses.)

So actually yes, the order of alternatives is important.
